# REDUCTIVE RELATIVE CLAUSES

Tags: relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

I've recently learnt about relative clauses from reading two websites. I see a conflict between them

- From the first source :https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/non-defining-relative-clauses/ ( about non-defining clauses )
  [image]

The last sentence of the small above passage means that **defining clauses will never stand after commas**, and you **can't leave out the relative pronoun in non-defining relative clauses**

- From the second source :https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107 ( about reductive relative clauses )

[image]

These are examples showing how to reduce a relative clauses. In the first example:

"The product, which seemed perfect in many ways, failed to succeed in the market. Reduced: The product, perfect in many ways, failed to succeed in the market"

In the origin sentence, the relative clause "which seemed perfect in many years" stands after commas, so **in the knowledge from the first source** => **it is a non-defining clause**. In the first source, however, the author also says that you **can't leave out the relative pronoun in non-defining relative clauses**, you can see in the "reduced sentence", **the pronoun "which" has been removed**.

So **Are two sources contradictory** ?. I'm looking forwards to your help. Thank you.

Comment: Despite what you may read, there's no such thing as a 'reduced relative clause'. The term is a misnomer. Non-finite clauses can be modifiers in NP structure, and even have the same meaning as relative clauses, but they are actually gerund-participial or past-participial clauses, not relative ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "reductive" shouldn't be substituted for "reduced", because it has a different meaning in English.

When a relative clause is "reduced" to an adjective phrase with equivalent meaning, it is no longer a relative clause, and in one of your two examples (perfect in many ways), it isn't a clause at all. In both cases, there is no pronoun remaining.

Note that the *non-defining* reduced forms in your examples are still set off by commas, because they still have non-essential information. They are adjuncts, and can be removed from the sentence without making it ungrammatical.

Here is an example of a *defining* relative clause reduced to an adjective phrase:

Relative clause:
*The boy who is pleased by his grades will probably like his teacher.*

(That is defining because it talks only about a boy pleased by his grades. One who is not pleased may not like his teacher.)

Adjective phrase:
*The boy pleased by his grades will probably like his teacher.*

Note that the reduced form "pleased by his grades" is still defining, and is not set off by commas.

Comment: Urgh, I do not like the adjective phrase version of that example.  That's how we get garden-path sentences like "The horse raced past the barn fell".

Answer (score 2):

BillJ has given you half the answer in his comment, but I'll expand it a bit.

A relative clause that is defining is not normally in a separate breath group (so if we happen to write it down, we don't use commas), and the relative pronoun may often be omitted: but it is still a finite clause, with a finite verb.

A non-defining (or non-restrictive) relative clause **is** in a separate breath group (so if we happen to write it down, we use commas), and you cannot omit the relative pronoun. It is a finite clause, with a finite verb.

The things your second source calls *Reduced relative clauses* are not relative clauses: the same meaning can usually be expressed by a relative clause, but that doesn't mean that they are relative clauses of any kind.

They are not finite clauses. They are adjectival phrases - your first example doesn't contain even a non-finite verb. The second one is a non-finite (participial) clause, functioning as an adjectival phrase.